# Android get Returned value from php

Tags: java, php, android, drupal-7, return

I am interfacing my Android app with my Drupal website.  In my app I am creating user accounts to that website using the standard PHP user_save.  What I need to move my app from the current activity to the next is a value to be returned form that PHP form which is creating my Drupal user account.

SO when an account is created, a value of 'invalid' or 'valid' would be returned from the php form like so:

```
  // User Authentication

  $responsep="valid";
  $responsen="invalid";

  if(!user_authenticate($username, $password)){
    drupal_json_output($responsen);

}else{

    // Logs the USER in 
    $account = user_authenticate($username, $password);
    $user = user_load($account, TRUE);
    drupal_session_regenerate();
    drupal_json_output($responsep);

}
```

Question is, how do I, in my android java method, retrieve that returned value of either valid or invalid so that I may use it to make other decisions such as try agin or change activities?

I have updated the code above

Here is the part from my App which is sending the user data:

```
public void createUserAccount(String usernameFinal, String passwordFinal,
        String userEmail) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    // POST Username data to php

    String uri = "https://url/hstusercreate.php"; 
    Log.d("Action", "Posting user data to php");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost getMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
    Log.d("Posting Location", uri);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    Log.d("Posting Username", usernameFinal);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernameFinal));

    Log.d("Posting Pass", passwordFinal);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordFinal));

    //Log.d("Posting Email", userEmail);
    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", userEmail));

    getMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
    client.execute(getMethod);
    Log.d("Action", "Finished Posting Data to PHP");

    // Return the message from php

    // If Successful then stop the creation of another user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to return either JSON or XML from your PHP which your app can then read and parse.

Actually you could even just print "valid" or "invalid" on the page, and then use something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) in your app to read the webpage and extract the string.